# Tense with "earlier"

Tags: grammar, tenses

Should I use the word 'earlier' with **simple past** or **present perfect** in the following context?

- It is clear that utilising the period of President's rule, the ruling party will indulge in all the methods in its arsenal to manufacture a majority for itself as it **has done/did** in several states **earlier**. This is yet another assault on the Constitution by this government.

Answer (score -1):

...as it has done in several states..... sounds better.